# doxygen: Table of contents broken in the pdf

Tags: c++, latex, doxygen, pdflatex

After running `Doxygen` on my `C++` code, I built the pdf documentation like this :

```
pdflatex refman.tex
```

All page numbers in the table of contents in the resulting `pdf` file are `??`. What could be the reason and how can it be fixed ?

**UPDATE**: Running `pdflatex` a second time fixes the table of contents...

Comment: Please use the make.bat / the Makefile as provided by doxygen, it tries by looping to resolve the missing page numbers and other wrong index numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not due to Doxygen but the way you generated the pdf with `pdflatex`.

You just have to recompile a second time with `pdflatex` to get the expected result.

Comment: yeah nervewrecking